# Android Improved Network Request Response Logging in Logcat

Tags: android, okhttp

My boss wants a better logging for network connection. He says we need more human-readable request-response log. We do already have [Stetho](https://medium.com/better-programming/stetho-the-best-debugging-tool-for-android-applications-1b1f0b99dc0e) and HttpLoggingInterceptor. I've searched in internet but couldn't find something different than these. Is there really better logging library I can use as my boss wanted ?

Answer (score 1):

FB Flipper is the replacement for Stetho.  A desktop app you run that connects and allows you to build plugins that talk to parts of your app like networking or UI layout. https://fbflipper.com/

I haven't tried it but https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit and https://github.com/httptoolkit/httptoolkit-android looks promising.

Or https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker